# Are there any good alternatives to SmarterMail?

Tags: email-server, email

For my ISV I'm using SmarterMail on my VPS. Everything works fine, except the fact that the SmarterMail service is very memory hungry. Right now it is setup to handle 2 domains and a handful accounts, and it allocates 250 MB. From my point of view it's a little bit too much.
The SmarterMail service is by far the most memory hungry process on my VPS right now. And I run a handful of IIs app pools and SQL Server.

Can anyone recommend a good alternative?

Requirements:

- Runs on 64bit Windows Server 2008
- Can handle DKIM/DOmainKeys
- Reasonable easy to set up
- IMAP support

Comment: What version of SmarterMail are you running?

Comment: @Dave: v5.5.3362

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up ditching the idea of running my own mail server. 
After all, a handful of domains, a handful of accounts.

Who am I kidding?

I did put everything on Google Apps.

Comment: Google Apps is unfortunately not cost effective at $50.00 per seat per year.

Answer (score 0):

You can look into Lotus domino mail server. Its affordable and not as memory intensive.
Also it will work with your SQL database as well. That would be my suggestion.

Steve